# Permutations Inverses

Tags: permutations, examples-counterexamples

I've trying to understand inverse's in permutations, so consider the permutation $T$ given by:

$T =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
 3& 2 & 4 & 5 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$   then $T^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
 5& 2 & 1 & 3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}$ would be it's inverse. But, I was wonder is it possible to have a permutation that isn't it's own inverse or is every permutation its own inverse?

Comment: Your example is a permutation that is not its own inverse.  If you compute $T^2$ it is not the identity.

Comment: While it is true that $(T^{-1})^{-1} = T$, it is not true that $T^{-1} = T$! Please see the difference between these statements, I think this is  your point of confusion.